# Word to represent whether something is wet or dry

Tags: grammar

I am looking for a word that can represent the wet/dry state of something, without actually using the word "state". Here is the context:
That dirt's ________ is wet/dry.
OR:
The _______ of that dirt is wet/dry

Similar to how you would represent male/female using **gender**, I need to represent wet/dry.

Comment: I have no idea what you just said there.

Comment: If on a form someone is wondering whether or not I am male or female, they have me list my GENDER. If on that same form someone is wondering whether or not I am wet or dry, I would list my ______.

Comment: Moisture level.

Comment: You may be looking for 'saturation', 'water content', 'fluid saturation', 'humidity', 'moisture' or another term. The term would depend on the use.

Comment: Exactly how it is being used is in computer programming. I am creating a list that contains the two items: wet and dry. I am needing to give this list a name. Currently saturation is sounding like a good word.

Comment: Naming programming variables is off-topic for this site.

Comment: Regardless of whether or not it is being used in programming, this is a question that could come up in any context/for any situation, which is why I did not directly list the use.I am open to any one of the various terms.

Comment: _wetness_ or _dryness_ would work for me.

Comment: In my opinion if I were to use wetness (as an example), it would not make much sense for an item's wetness to be "Dry". Or for an item's dryness to be "Wet".

Comment: I would generally say "dampness".

Comment: What @HotLicks said: *dampness*. Or *moistness*. Or *wetness*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a single word where a variable *level* or *amount* of *fluid* content is implied by the context, 'saturation' may be the ticket. 'Humidity' and 'moisture' run close seconds, and may be better in circumstances where the variability of the quantity (level or amount) is not implied.

Were it not for the close popular association of 'humidity' with *air*, resulting from use with that reference in weather report broadcasting, that term would be preferable to the more general 'saturation'.

> saturation (ˌsætʃəˈreɪʃən) n 1. the act of saturating ....

and so from

> saturate vb 1. to fill, soak ....

[saturate. (n.d.) Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged. (1991, 1994, 1998, 2000, 2003). Retrieved October 30 2015 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/saturate.]

Answer (score 0):

**humidity/wetness**

*the condition of containing or being covered by a liquid (especially water); "he confirmed the wetness of the swimming trunks"*